# How to add/remove tags in mp3 with php?

Tags: php, file, mp3, id3

I download a remote file from `file_get_contents()` like this:

```
$myaudio = file_get_contents("url");
```

How, I want to add a ID3 tag `artist`, remove all other tags including cover image.

How to do this?

Comment: You can use the id3 extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.setup.php

Comment: How to remove cover image with that? @hek2mgl

Comment: I've never tried that. You need to play around with it and read the id3 specs

Comment: The PHP ID3 library can only remove/add text based tags, not the cover.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114357/setting-album-art-of-a-mp3-with-php

Comment: May be this could help [http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ID3v2](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ID3v2)

Comment: @maniteja Without Zend please.

Comment: @DanMan That answer shows the technical side. Plus, getId3() does not have a documentation. That's why I need help.